# Android change recycler view column no. on pinch zoom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pinchzoom, android-touch-event

I have in my layout recycler view for gallery application.

I want to incorporate a pinch touch event listner such that the recycler view column no. increases or decreases on pich in and out.

I have seen this type of interface in many gallery application.

What is the best way to acheive this so that the transition is smooth.

Small Video link :- http://sendvid.com/s68fiqpd

I tried using below code (as provided by @Yogesh Rathi) but results is not what I want to achieve.

```
   import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;

/**
@author yogesh
* */
public class PinchRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private float maxWidth = 0.0f;
    private float maxHeight = 0.0f;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float width;
    private float height;


    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                /* this line is replaced because here came below isssue
                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
                 ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919292/pointerindex-out-of-range-android-multitouch
                */
                //final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                if (mPosX > 0.0f)
                    mPosX = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosX < maxWidth)
                    mPosX = maxWidth;

                if (mPosY > 0.0f)
                    mPosY = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosY < maxHeight)
                    mPosY = maxHeight;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
            mPosX = 0.0f;
            mPosY = 0.0f;
        }
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
            maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
            maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use Scale gesture detector together with layout managers in recycler view to achieve this. I have done something similar but don't have code for that right now. set on touch listener on your recycler view and pass the touch event to an instance of scale gesture detector. In onScale() function you can toggle layouts managers for your recycler view based on scale factor.

Comment: I tried Scale gesture also, but using that blocks the normal scrolling on recycler view

Comment: I have created a demo. Check this: https://gitlab.com/ankit_aggarwal/PinchDemo.git   it is not smooth though but scroll is working

Comment: maybe something can be done to make it smooth. Some animation can be provided. Right now I am simply changing layout manager at particular scale value but we scale based on scale factor

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal U tried the project which you shared, but other then animation the pinch has some issue. After I pinch in and set layout to maximun  three column and then when I pinch in again then it first changes to two column and then back to three column. Same way for pinch out with one column layout. How do we resolve this.

Comment: I have fixed that bug and committed the code. But middle state is not visible most of the time. Also it is not smooth. But I think something can be done to make it smooth

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Ankit I have not tried your updated code yet, will check tommorow. I would like to award the bounty to you. So plz post your code as an answer. Will let you know if updated code workes well or not. Thanks

Comment: did the code work?

Comment: I have fixed the issues and it is working. Although it is too sensitive.

Answer (score 10):

**This the way to pinch in and out,I already checked this in my example app working properly.**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;

/**
@author yogesh
* */
public class PinchRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private float maxWidth = 0.0f;
    private float maxHeight = 0.0f;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float width;
    private float height;


    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                /* this line is replaced because here came below isssue
                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
                 ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919292/pointerindex-out-of-range-android-multitouch
                */
                //final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                if (mPosX > 0.0f)
                    mPosX = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosX < maxWidth)
                    mPosX = maxWidth;

                if (mPosY > 0.0f)
                    mPosY = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosY < maxHeight)
                    mPosY = maxHeight;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
            mPosX = 0.0f;
            mPosY = 0.0f;
        }
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
            maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
            maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code the Recycler View is getting zoomed in and out. What change do I made to increase (or decrease) column number on pinch action?

Comment: Great code ! I also need to change the layout manager on zoom. How do I achieve the same.

Comment: Just to note that `onDraw()` does nothing. Could be removed.

Comment: @Yogesh Rathi, Your code is working properly but it is not as smooth as normal zoom in/out, How can I make it smooth in terms of zoom in/out.

Comment: MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG ?

Comment: @Trk you can use canvas.save(); instead of canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scale gesture detector together with layout managers in recycler view to achieve this. set on touch listener on your recycler view and pass the touch event to an instance of scale gesture detector. In onScale() function you can toggle layouts managers for your recycler view based on scale factor. I have created a demo for this. You can find the code [here](https://gitlab.com/ankit_aggarwal/PinchDemo)