# How to make Zoom on whole content in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need zoom in/out on whole content in RecyclerView. 
In fact I need to resize all child views by width, and text inside each item.

```
public class ViewHolder {

    Button btn;

    ...
}
```

When User make zoom in, the text of Button should be decrease down to `8sp` and disappear if user continue zoom in.

So, now I have dilemma : what I need to do? Resize items in Adapter, or resize them in LayoutManager, and update whole adapter.

Both of scenarios seems affect an performance of visual effect, so I need help. Maybe you give me a better solution.

---

For state of 21/11/2016 I can't found any box-solution for this case.
So I decide write my own view and do remeasurement of visible views in each zoom scale factor change.

Answer (score 0):

Which adapter do you use?

I've tried Horizontal LinearLayoutManager and do resize items inside adapter:

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           ...
           final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewHolder.rootView.getLayoutParams();
           layoutParams.width = getItemWidth(position);   //width calculation using current zoom level
           layoutParams.height = mItemLayoutHeight;
           viewHolder.rootView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
           ...
```

and setZoom(..) method of the activity/fragment looks like:

```
        public void setZoom(float newValue) {
           int dScroll = (int) ((ADAPTER_ZOOM - newValue) * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2f);   //assume you Recycler view uses whole display 
           ADAPTER_ZOOM = newValue;
           resetBoundaries();
           //
           epgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           //
           epgRecyclerView.scrollBy(dScroll, 0);
        }
```

But with my custom LayoutManager performance is bad, seems there is a list of optimisations inside the LinearLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

for complete implementation refer to :
github.com/mosayeb-masoumi/zoom_whole_recyclerview

Answer (score -2):

**user this code. it's working fine for zooming all content of recyclerview.**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;

/**
@author yogesh
* */
public class PinchRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private float maxWidth = 0.0f;
    private float maxHeight = 0.0f;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float width;
    private float height;


    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                /* this line is replaced because here came below isssue
                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
                 ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919292/pointerindex-out-of-range-android-multitouch
                */
                //final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                if (mPosX > 0.0f)
                    mPosX = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosX < maxWidth)
                    mPosX = maxWidth;

                if (mPosY > 0.0f)
                    mPosY = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosY < maxHeight)
                    mPosY = maxHeight;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
            mPosX = 0.0f;
            mPosY = 0.0f;
        }
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
            maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
            maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Code taken from this StackOverflow answer: [Android change recycler view column no. on pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772918/android-change-recycler-view-column-no-on-pinch-zoom)

Comment: Just include a link to the answer is not a good one. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.